# DM74LS00 Voltage drop

Tags: digital-logic

i was using this NAND gate, and with inputs as 1 & 0, output is 112mv and 4.1 V,
what is the reason for the rise or drop in the voltage at the output?

Comment: You're well within spec for the chip and the logic family.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the output circuitry of a TTL gate you'll find something like this.

[image]

**OUTPUT LOW**

When the output is LOW then TR3 is turned ON and TR2 is OFF. The Tr3 transistor will be in saturation which means there will be a small voltage, V4, ( about 0.1 - 0.2 volts) at the output when **sinking** a current (your meter or a ttl 'input'). This voltage will increase with increasing sink current. This ties in nicely with your measurement of 112mV.

**OUTPUT HIGH**

When the output is HIGH TR3 is OFF and TR2 is ON but we now we have **THREE voltages drops before the output**.

(1) A drop across the 130 ohm resistor  -  V1

(2) A drop across Tr2  -  V2

(3) A drop across D1  -   V3

Now V2 is in the region of about 0.1 - 0.2V, V3 will be about 0.6V and V1 depends on the output current. So a loss of 0.9V (mainly V2 + V3) is quite reasonable when the output is **sourcing** a very small current (your meter) and once again ties in with your measurement of 4.1V.

At no time are both Tr2 and Tr3 turned on together.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is perfect, the transistors that 'close' the output to ground and power drop a certain (current-dependent) voltage. Check the datasheet for the details.